# Get bluetooth data from a scale device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

i am using this plugin : https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

i can scan bluetooth devices, my scale is detected and i can connect to it
but i can't get any data from the device.

what is the process to get data from a bluetooth device with that plugin?

here some code error:

```
 W/PluginManager( 5949): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to BLE.stopScan blocked the main thread for 24ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
D/BluetoothGatt( 5949): connect() - device: 7C:66:9D:9E:46:31, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt( 5949): registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt( 5949): registerApp() - UUID=08a761d6-34e9-4db3-8c58-258786ad7c3c
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2228): registerClient() - UUID=08a761d6-34e9-4db3-8c58-258786ad7c3c
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2228): onClientRegistered() - UUID=08a761d6-34e9-4db3-8c58-258786ad7c3c, clientIf=5
D/BluetoothGatt( 5949): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2228): clientConnect() - address=7C:66:9D:9E:46:31, isDirect=true
D/btif_config( 2228): btif_get_address_type: Device [7c:66:9d:9e:46:31] address type 0
D/btif_config( 2228): btif_get_device_type: Device [7c:66:9d:9e:46:31] type 2
D/cr_Ime  ( 5949): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime  ( 5949): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
E/bt-btm  ( 2228): Random unmatch
W/bt-btm  ( 2228): btm_acl_created hci_handle=2 link_role=0  transport=2
W/bt-btif ( 2228): info:x0
W/bt-l2cap( 2228): L2CA_SetDesireRole() new:x0, disallow_switch:0
D/        ( 2228): remote version info [7c:66:9d:9e:46:31]: 0, 0, 0
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2228): onConnected() - clientIf=5, connId=5, address=7C:66:9D:9E:46:31
D/BluetoothGatt( 5949): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=7C:66:9D:9E:46:31
D/BluetoothGatt( 5949): discoverServices() - device: 7C:66:9D:9E:46:31
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2228): discoverServices() - address=7C:66:9D:9E:46:31, connId=5
E/bt-btif ( 2228): No More Service found
D/BtGatt.GattService( 2228): onSearchCompleted() - connId=5, status=0
D/BluetoothGatt( 5949): onSearchComplete() = Device=7C:66:9D:9E:46:31 Status=0
E/PluginManager( 5949): Uncaught exception from plugin
E/PluginManager( 5949): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "0000null"
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:363)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at java.lang.Long.parsePositiveLong(Long.java:413)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:190)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at com.megster.cordova.ble.central.UUIDHelper.uuidFromString(UUIDHelper.java:32)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at com.megster.cordova.ble.central.BLECentralPlugin.uuidFromString(BLECentralPlugin.java:573)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at com.megster.cordova.ble.central.BLECentralPlugin.execute(BLECentralPlugin.java:163)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:117)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:133)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/PluginManager( 5949):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/cr_BindingManager( 5949): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 5949
D/HeadsetStateMachine( 2228): Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0
```

Comment: Dear kratosphere, please give a snippet of your code where you are trying to connect and read data from the device.

Answer (score 0):

1. The bluetooth devices have services and characteristics, a service can have one or more characteristics.
2. The data you need to read is stored in some characteristic, all you need to do is find the right characteristic to read.
3. First print the peripheral once you connect to it.

```js
ble.connect(deviceMac,function(peripheral){
  console.log(peripheral);   //print your peripheral
},function(){
  console.log("error connecting");
})
```

In the console.you can find the services and characteristic. After finding the right one, start notifications on that characteristic. The code for it:

```js
var service="ffe0"; //or appropriate uuid
var characteristic="ffe1" //or appropriate uuid
ble.startNotification(deviceMac,service,characteristic,function(data){
   try{
       console.log(bytesToString(data)); //convert the array buffer into readable string
   }catch(e){
       console.log(e);
   }
},
function(){
   console.log("error starting notifications.");
});

function bytesToString(buffer) 
{    
    var arr = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);
    if(/[\u0080-\uffff]/.test(str))
    {
        throw new Error("this string seems to contain (still encoded) multibytes");
    }
    return str;
}
```

I think the connection to the peripheral is getting lost somewhere, make sure you stay connected to the peripheral before exchanging data. If you like share the code with me.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer i added the good service and characteristic id and i got this in output log: 01-05 17:47:53.736 26344 26356 W CordovaPlugin: Result was: {"name":"Samico Scales","id":"7C:66:9D:9E:46:31","errorMessage":"Peripheral Disconnected"}
01-05 17:47:53.736 26344 26356 D BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 7C:66:9D:9E:46:31

Comment: and this in console JS: Error in Success callbackId: BLE1615781344 : Error: this string seems to contain (still encoded) multibytes

Comment: Hello, i think there is a connection problem somewhere in the code, your device gets disconnected.